# C# eBay OAuth Compliance API Authentication Problems

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, ebay-api, getresponsestream

After many struggles, I was finally able to get the OAuth Authentication/Refresh token process down.  I am certain that the tokens I am using in this process are good.  But I am struggling to communicate with the Compliance API and I think it may have more to do with my headers authentication process than it does specifically the Compliance API but I am not certain.  I've tried so many different combinations of the below code unsuccessfully.  I've tried to do the call as a GET and a POST (the call should be a GET).  I've tried it with the access token encoded and not encoded.  With all of my different code combinations tried I've been getting either an authorization error or a bad request error.  You can see some of the various things I've tried from commented out code. Thank you for your help.

```
public static string Complaince_GetViolations(string clientId, string ruName, string clientSecret, string accessToken, ILog log)
{
var clientString = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
//byte[] clientEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientString);
//var credentials = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(clientEncode);

byte[] clientEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accessToken);
var credentials = "Bearer " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(clientEncode);

var codeEncoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken);

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.ebay.com/sell/compliance/v1/listing_violation?compliance_type=PRODUCT_ADOPTION")   
as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "GET";
//  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, credentials);
//request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + codeEncoded);
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, credentials);
//request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + codeEncoded);
request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY-US");


log.Debug("starting request.GetRequestStream");
string result = "";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) //FAILS HERE
{
    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

//DO MORE STUFF BELOW
return "STUFF";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I finally figured out a resolution to this problem. The HTML encoding of the entire bearer string was the issue.  If anyone needs this in the future your welcome. =)

```
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.ebay.com/sell/compliance/v1/listing_violation?compliance_type=PRODUCT_ADOPTION")   
        as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Bearer " + accessToken));
        request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY-US");

        log.Debug("starting request.GetRequestStream");
        string result = null;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```